# The order method disordered my data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, decimal

The problem here is the ordering is not working normally.
The "gross_profit" values are not sorted in order, they are completely disordered.

Below, I've posted a part of my code without things that don't rely to this problem (I hope).

db/migrate/create_projets.rb :

```
t.decimal :prix, :precision => 16, :scale => 2
t.decimal :total_expenditures, :precision => 16, :scale => 2
t.decimal :gross_profit, :precision => 16, :scale => 2
```

The price attribute is recorded by the user in a form.
The others are calculated in the model below.

db/migrate/create_depenses.rb :

```
t.decimal :prix, :precision => 16, :scale => 2
t.decimal :quantite, :default => 1, :precision => 16, :scale => 2
```

These two attributes are recorded by the user in a form.

app/models/projet.rb :

```
has_many :depenses

def set_total_expenditures
    total_expenditures = 0
    self.depenses.each do |d|
        total_expenditures += d.quantite*d.prix
    end
    return total_expenditures
end

def set_gross_profit
    self.prix - self.set_total_expenditures
end

def record_all
    self.total_expenditures = set_total_expenditures
    self.gross_profit = set_gross_profit
end

after_find :record_all
```

I've build the "record_all" method because it seems the order method accepts only data from columns, and not data from a simple method in my model.

app/controllers/projets_controller.rb :

```
def index
    @projets = Projet.order("gross_margin desc")
end
```

app/views/projets/index.html.erb :

```
<table>
<% @projets.each do |p| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= p.prix %></td>
          <td><%= p.total_expenditures %></td>
          <td><%= p.gross_profit %></td>
        </tr>
<% end %>
<table>
```

I've thinked maybe it's because BigDecimals were transformed in Float at a moment in the app, but this thing normally just bring a bit of inaccuracy at worst, so this is not the problem here.

Or maybe the problem is coming from the special pattern I've used in the "record_all" method ? But I don't see where exactly if it is here...

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Ditch the `all`:

```
@projets = Project.order("gross_margin desc")
```

Note the reorder option in the [docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/order), in case a default scope, association definition, or something else is causing a pre-existing sort.

Comment: Yes, I've removed the `all` and edited my post, it was not present in the original code. It's an error when I've posted my code here because I've removed some code that don't rely to the problem.
And, I've tested the reorder option but it has'nt solved the problem.
I've got a default-scope (because it's a multi-tenant application) but there isn't any order method in this default-scope.

Answer (score 0):

Your index action should be

```
def index
    @projets = Projet.order(gross_margin: :desc)
end
```

Comment: Yes, I've answered in the comments of the Brad's answer.